# How to display Image grid in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to show images in table format like below in MVC-4

```
-------------------------------
|  Image  |  image  |  Image  |
-------------------------------
|  Image  |  image  |  Image  |
-------------------------------
|  Image  |  image  |  Image  |
-------------------------------

Paging display records 0-9 of page 1

<<   <   1   2   3   >   >>
```

For this in simple ASP.NET I am using DataList or repeater and in MVC4 I am using partial View but I am not able to show in that view like above format so can anyone help me to create partial view like above?

Or if you have any better idea then please guide me which type of control I should use for this.

If you have any reference link then it will also very helpful to me.

View:

```
@foreach 
(var item in Model) 
{ 
    <tr> 
    <td>
    @
    {
        string img; 
        if (item.AgentImage != null) 
        { 
            img = item.AgentImage.Replace("~", ".."); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            img = item.AgentImage; 
        }
    } 
    <img src = '@img' height="80px" width="100px" /> 
    </td> 
    </tr> 
}
```

Comment: Could you paste code from your mvc view?

Comment: at now i have completed coding for controller and model and trying to show images in partial view but i am not able to display in webgrid because if i use that then it will show in single column like gridview.. i have to create view like above with paging if u have any suggestion then please help..

Comment: Paste your code. Without it we cannot help you because we don't know were you made a mistake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713247/html5-css-re-flow-grid-layout

Comment: at now i have added foreach loop ---    @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@{string img; if (item.AgentImage != null) { img = item.AgentImage.Replace("~", ".."); } else { img = item.AgentImage; }}
                        <img src = '@img' height="80px" width="100px"  />
                    </td> </tr>
            }

Comment: @Garath but i am not getting required result.. with paging. for paging i am trying to use http://mvcpaging.apphb.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your code in view looks like you wrote in comment. You need to add rows every third element.
The simplest change into your code could look like following:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) { 
    <tr> <td>
        @{
            string img; 

            if (item.AgentImage != null) 
            { img = item.AgentImage.Replace("~", ".."); } 
            else 
            { img = item.AgentImage; }

            var i=0;
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                Html.Raw("</tr><tr>"); //End old row and start new one
            }
            i++;
        } 
        <img src = '@img' height="80px" width="100px" /> 
    </td></tr> 
}
```